# ICM vs FGS in spin & go's

Tags: poker-theory, icm

I am trying to set up some **general** ranges in spin & go's. For example what hands I should be shoving in the SB vs the BB with x amount of blinds.

ICM nash equilibrium is the easiest method to calculate this with. Since there is no payout pressure only effective stacks matter. It doesn't matter whether the button has 500 or 100000 chips.

However, ICM is not accurate in this spot, since it doesn't take your position into account. The next hand you play, will be free of charge, which means you can fold more hands in the small blind and wait for a better spot.

To solve this problem [FGS (future game simulations)](http://www.icmpoker.com/en/blog/icm-to-fgs-future-game-simulations/) is used. ICMizer (the program that I use) offers FGS1 all the way to FGS6, which simply means 1 turn to 6 turns ahead. However, FGS takes much more into consideration when calculating the nash equilibrium. This way it is pretty much impossible to set up general ranges, since they will always differ a little bit.

I decided to just use ICM, but I found out that in some spots ICM advices to shove 10-14% more hands than FGS, which is a huge difference.

How can I calculate reasonably accurate ranges in an easy way? Perhaps ICM is fine to use, since players at the low stakes play a little too tight anyway. What do you think?

Comment: @paparazzi is asking this on math forum ever an option? Or 2+2?

Answer (score 1):

ICM does not apply (i.e., does not bring any value) to winner-take-all tournaments. Each chip has a fixed value all the time: prize pool divided by total number of chips in play.